# Toggle selected options in select form elements using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have two `select` elements in a form. When `b` is selected in the one element, `z` must be selected in the other element.

At the moment when I test the below implementation, this toggle functionality works for a while and then stops working at a point where I switch from selecting an option on the one element to selecting an option on the other element.

I cannot find a pattern to identify what is going on but I think there is a duplication in logic.

The idea is to expand the lists of options on both elements at a later point but for now I just want to get the toggle effect to work.

```
$("#5").change(function() {

    if ($('#5').val() == 'b') {

        $('#6').find('option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
        $('#6 option[value=z]').attr('selected', 'selected');

    } else if ($('#5').val() == 'z') {

        $('#6').find('option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
        $('#6 option[value=b]').attr('selected', 'selected');

    }

})

$("#6").change(function() {

    if ($('#6').val() == 'b') {

        $('#5').find('option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
        $('#5 option[value=z]').attr('selected', 'selected');

    } else if ($('#6').val() == 'z') {

        $('#5').find('option:selected').removeAttr("selected");
        $('#5 option[value=b]').attr('selected', 'selected');

    }

})
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Unless these are selects with a multiple attribute, you don't need to "remove attribute selected". Also the #id values are not up to HTML spec.

Comment: Could you not combine the ids together and then just change when one of them changes? so... `$("#5, #6").change(function()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

> - Use jQuery's [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) method instead!
> - Use `$(this)` inside the selector, to fetch the current object

```js
$(function(){

  $("#5").change(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == 'b') {

          $('#6').find('option:selected').prop("selected", false);
          $('#6 option[value=z]').prop('selected', true);

      } else if ($(this).val() == 'z') {

          $('#6').find('option:selected').prop("selected", false);
          $('#6 option[value=b]').prop('selected', true);

      }

  })

  $("#6").change(function() {

      if ($(this).val() == 'b') {

          $('#5').find('option:selected').prop("selected", false);
          $('#5 option[value=z]').prop('selected', true);

      } else if ($(this).val() == 'z') {

          $('#5').find('option:selected').prop("selected", false);
          $('#5 option[value=b]').prop('selected', true);

      }

  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <select id="5">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="z">z</option>
    <option value="x">x</option>
  </select>
  
  <select id="6">
    <option value="a">a</option>
    <option value="b">b</option>
    <option value="z">z</option>
    <option value="x">x</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: This does work. Any idea what is wrong with my own code? This doesn't appear to be a browser related issue.

Comment: Also why did you change `.change(...` to `.on('change', ...`? `.change(...` is still working perfectly fine.

Comment: No need of changing `.change()`, the problem of your code is `.attr()` method thats it, you should use `prop('property_name', true)` instead

Comment: @AdriaanJoubert - If you find this answer correct and helpful then accept & upvote this answer as it motivates me to give answers to other questions like this and helps others to quickly find the correct answer!